# Why use Dispatcher.Invoke((ThreadStart)delegate...in WPF?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, controls, dispatcher

I usually use `Dispatcher.Invoke` when i need to access some UI elements from background thread. Recently i had to change other's written sources and i saw that same tasks he accomplishes with constructions like:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke((ThreadStart)delegate
            {
              //some code that uses controls from UI
            });
```

When should i use such code instead of `Dispatcher.Invoke/BeginInvoke` and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That *does* use `Dispatcher.Invoke` - it's not an "instead of". That code is just using `ThreadStart` as a way of telling the compiler the delegate type to convert the anonymous method to.

It's equivalent to:

```
ThreadStart tmp = delegate
{
    // Code
};
Dispatcher.Invoke(tmp);
```

Personally I'd use `Action` instead of `ThreadStart` here as you're not actually starting a thread, but it's a pretty arbitrary choice. Ignore the fact that it's called `ThreadStart` - it's *just* a delegate with a void return type and no parameters.

EDIT: The reason you have to specify *a* delegate type is that the compiler can't convert an anonymous function (i.e. an anonymous method or a lambda expression) to just `Delegate`, which is the argument type of `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

One workaround for this is to write an extension method:

```
public static void InvokeAction(this Dispatcher dispatcher, Action action)
{
    dispatcher.Invoke(action);
}
```

You can then use:

```
foo.Dispatcher.InvokeAction(() => { /* stuff */ });
```

and the compiler knows to convert the lambda expression to `Action`.

Comment: ooops...missed the handler. So if i write such code-i tell that i will use this method on "thread"...But "everything" is threads.. So the method can be executed anywhere(then why do we need that conversion)? May be thats stupid question, sorry then, but can you provide some material on theme?(i really see that i miss something :()

Comment: If i understood correctly: `ThreadStart` here is optional, just to give delegate "some" type?

Comment: You are the best! Thank you for clarification with explanation!